# How do I give my desktop app access to download a file on a Google shared drive?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have the following script where I'm trying to download a file from a Google Shared Drive that I created and have uploaded a file. It's pretty basic:

```
    file_id = '12345asdf'

    request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    file = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(file, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print(F'Download {int(status.progress() * 100)}.')
```

However, I'm getting an error: `An error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/12345asdf?alt=media returned "The user has not granted the app 123456318123 read access to the file 12345asdf.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'appNotAuthorizedToFile', 'message': 'The user has not granted the app 123456318123 read access to the file 12345asdf.', 'locationType': 'header', 'location': 'Authorization'}]">`

This is the current definition of scopes:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
```

Do I need updated scopes, or how do I explicitly give my app permission to download the file?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot that whenever you change scopes, you need to re-authenticate and re-run. My app was still using the old scopes definition